# Почему html на сайте отличается от html полученного в python 3

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, requests

Я пытаюсь сделать парсер инфы про шиномонтаж. Получилось собрать все необходимые ссылки, вот некоторые из них

```
https://sankt-petersburg.kupibonus.ru/actions/auto/moyka-kuzova-himchistka-salona-polirovka-235282/
https://sankt-petersburg.kupibonus.ru/actions/auto/shinomontazh-kolesocity-235495/
https://sankt-petersburg.kupibonus.ru/actions/auto/shinomontazh-i-balansirovka-koles-235496/
https://sankt-petersburg.kupibonus.ru/actions/auto/shinomontazh-i-balansirovka-233396/
```

Далее если в браузере открыть любую из ссылок, то можно найти `<div id="tab-description"`, вот этот `id` мне и нужен, но если получить ссылку через функцию, через которую я ссылки парсил:

```
def get_html(self, url=None):
    HDR = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'}
    req = urllib.request.Request(self.url, headers=HDR)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    html = str(response.read())
    return html
```

То на в получаемом `html` нет `<div id="tab-description"`.

В чем проблема и возможно ли ее как то решить?

Comment: *>В чем проблема* - контент подгружается с помощью JavaScript. *>Как решить* - смотреть, что и как делает этот JavaScript, эмулировать эти действия из питона, либо использовать эмулятор браузера (например, `selenium`).

Comment: selenium - это не эмулятор, а средство управления браузером. Он запускает обычный браузер со слоем интеграционного API. Подходят Firefox, Chrome, Chromium-based (Opera, MS Edge), MS IE.